# NPE when searching element in the LinkedList

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linked-list

i'm searching an element in the LinkedList, output is correct when the element is indeed in the list. However, testing the opposite case, when searching for Null or element not in the list, NPE happens. Please help, thanks!

```
public boolean find(E e){
    Node current=head;
    while(current.item !=null){
        if(e.equals(current.item)){
            System.out.println("True");
            return true;
        }
        current=current.next;
    }
    System.out.println("False");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: 0.02 => consider doing `System.out.println(yourList.find(e));` rather than printing out of the method.

Answer (score 2):

The `while` statement should be `while(current !=null)`

Answer (score 1):

May be you need to change the condition in while loop:

```
public boolean find(E e){
    Node current=head;
    while(current != null){
        if( (current.item != null) && (e.equals(current.item)){
            System.out.println("True");
            return true;
        }
        current=current.next;
    }
    System.out.println("False");
    return false;
}
```

Also check if item in the node is not `null`.